# Understanding vector/mean functions in R

Tags: r

[image]

Hi, I was looking to see if anyone could help me.

So I am new to using R and I'm following through a workbook provided by my univesity and have been trying the functions out in R and changing various numbers to see how this changed the information.

Generally, I have been understanding most of it but I dont quite understand some of the following code.

Could anyone explain to me what

> vec.mean <- numeric(N)

means as im not entirely sure what this is doing.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1):

If you read the help file with `help(numeric)`:

> **Description** -
> Creates or coerces objects of type "numeric".

> **Arguments** -
> length
> A non-negative integer specifying the desired length. Double values will be coerced to integer: supplying an argument of length other than one is an error.

The first argument of `numeric()` is `length =`. Therefore, `numeric(500)` creates a numeric vector of length 500.

This is theoretically a best practice because running the `for` loop later on a vector that has already been created will have subtly improved performance.

Comment: Ahh okay I undestand, thank you for your comment. Is there any chance you could help me understand the next line as well? I understand that using 'for' creates a loop function starting at a size of 1 from the random sample and then repeating until we get to the sample size N. And that 'TRUE' means that it can repeat the same values but this is where I get stuck again.